# Selenium grid hub and node on same machine with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-grid

i trying to run a selenium grid test case using C# . I am using same machine for hub and node. 
To strat node

```
D:\Selenium>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role webdriver -hub
 http://10.74.224.251:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=internet explorer,
platform=WINDOWS version=7 -port 5556 -dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\Selenium\DLL\IED
riverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe"
```

and to start hub

```
D:\Selenium\DLL>java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\Selenium\DLL\IEDriverServer_Win32
_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role hub
```

and in C# i have write following code

```
IWebDriver driver;
            string baseURL, nodeURL;
            baseURL = "https://www.google.co.in/";
            nodeURL = "http://10.74.224.251:5556/wd/hub";

            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.ie.driver", @"D:\Selenium\DLL\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();

            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "internet explorer");
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "7");
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(nodeURL), capabilities);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
```

but code not execute and throw following error each time

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
Additional information: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
The program '[8472] Selenium First Project.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

But i should do or any one have sample code for the same

Thanks

Comment: Java System Properties != Environment Variables...

Comment: At which line do you get this error?

Comment: i got this error on this line 
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(nodeURL), capabilities);